# How can you view the filename of a webpage if it has been hidden

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out the name of the default page of a domain for a site i'm working on.

It has been set so that the name of the default page isn't shown, so it just shows the domain name in the address bar and ends after .com/

Is there any way to view what the name of this file is?

Comment: Here's a question for your question: suppose the web server generates the entire page from data in memory, without reading any file whatsoever. What would the filename be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark: if your web server is Apache and there is a .htaccess file in the root folder look into it for a line starting with *DirectoryIndex*. If it's there the first filename would be the default.

Answer (score 2):

<s>No there isn't.</s> Quite probably it's index.php

Comment: I've got cpanel access and FTP access, but there are two sites hosted on the server. I see the files for one of the sites, and in an old backup of the site I see files which relate to the one i'm trying to edit. However in the main live www directory the folder from the backup is not there. So it is either being served from that backup folder, which would be odd, or somewhere else.

Comment: If you have ftp access to the site that changes situation a lot. See your webserver configuration to see what page is being served as the default one. If you're on Apache, look for .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

I not quite sure I understood your question, I just hope I can help:

The server hides the /filename when it is the default one, index.html or index.php or default.html or something of that kind.

You say you have two sites on the server.

I don´t know you service provider but with cPanel in some accounts types (not dedicated) inside your public_html folder you should see a directory called "your_second_sites_name.com" and there you will have and index.html that would be your second´s site  public_html.

I hope this helps you out if no, please add a comment and I´ll gladly edit my answer! good luck!